# How can liquid enzymatic drain decloggers reach the clog in a toilet drain?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, drain, clog

I added liquid enzymatic drain "declogger" *(brand: Earthworm)* to a clogged toilet drain that I already tried plunging.

How are the enzymes supposed to reach the clog, unless the clog is in the first half of the P-trap?  If the clog is already beyond that, it seems like the enzymes will just be working in the area of the drain already cleared.

Comment: Well if the specific gravity of the chemical will allow the chemical to reach the "plug"  and start to dissolve it I would suggest that that was the best way to go. I am an electrician with only high school chemistry but that would make sense to me.

Comment: Whether or not it reaches the clog, the Earthworm manufacturer still makes money.  :-)  I've never found chemical or enzyme products to be very useful.  If you're sure the clog is just stuff that belongs there (i.e., not children's toys or feminine products), it can usually be cleared with hot water and soap.  If the water goes down even really slowly, let it drain out.  Squirt a little liquid soap in the bowl, a little bleach for odor control, and pour in a large pot of hot (almost boiling) water.  Wait for that to drain out and repeat as needed.  (cont'd)

Comment: Clogs usually clear by about the 3rd pot of water.  If the clog doesn't clear by the 4th or 5th pot, you'll need to break out a plunger or snake, but that's rare.

Comment: I use sulphuric-acid based drain cleaner, it usually does its work on first litre of product... I tryed "bio" products/boiling water and didn't solved in hours what my good old acid cleans in one 20-minutes strike. The only thing to check is not to have any lead drain plumbing. (Lead would oxidize and release huge amounts of explosive hydrogen sulphide). PS: it reaches the clog only if there arn't P-pipes, if you have siphons the manifacturer suggest to use rubber hose to pass it then pour it by the hose (or huge amounts are needed)

Comment: I don’t care for acidic drain cleaner because they tend to permanently damage chrome drain pieces, acidic is usually not meant for toilets where the maker admits on the bottle the heat from the reaction can cause other toilet problems, including cracking.  Enzymatic drain cleaners do work but not on already plugged drains, enzymes when used as directed are great for preventive maintenance.  When a drain is plugged the best solution is a snake.  If tree roots are a regular problem flushing copper sulphate works well, but again as a preventative treatment, not after plug.

Comment: Thanks to all for the tips everyone.  @fixer1234 How do you avoid damaging the wax seal, as mentioned in https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/52705/27414 ?

Comment: I suppose that if almost boiling water sits in the bowl long enough, the heat could migrate and soften the wax ring.  I've never run into that, myself (at least that I'm aware of), but it would be a good reason to use moderation and not overdo it.  It's a "clean" way to clear the clog, and if it's going to work on a specific clog, it works within the first few pots of water.  So I guess good advice would be to give up on staying clean if it doesn't work in the first few pots.

Comment: @fixer1234 and everyone Thanks for all your input!  Drain finally unclogged.  In the end, Earthworm and proper plunging technique (sharp upward motion) got it open.  Took two doses of the Earthworm, letting it sit over two nights and enough plunging that I think I've earned some sort of certificate.  My next step was going to be the hot water and soap trick.

Comment: Add water and plunge the stuff. Some of it will make it over the top of the siphon, where it can do some good.